# Next.jsでsleep機能をexportしたい

Tags: javascript, aws, amazon-s3, next.js

AWSのS3とCloud　Frontを用いて、静的Webサイトを公開します。
Next.jsで生成したサイトをアップしたのですが、ローディング画面が機能しません。
page.tsxにて以下のように記述したところ、ローカルでは2700ミリ秒待機してる間に、loading.tsxを表示してくれます。

```
const sleep = (msec: number) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, msec));

export default async function Home() {
  await sleep(2700);
  return (
    <>
      <main ...
```

その後、npm run buildを実行し、outディレクトリに静的ファイルを生成しました。
S3にアップしましたが、ローディング画面が表示されず、いきなりTOPページが表示されてしまいました。
out配下のファイルを検索して、2700ミリ秒の表記があるか確認しましたが、ヒットしなかったためファイルが生成されていないのだと思います。
loading.tsxの内容は生成されているので、sleepのような待機させるような処理を生成したいです。
await sleep(2700);も生成されるようにしたいのですが何か方法はないでしょうか。